# Efficient way to find elements in list out of order

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given this list

```
[True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False]
```

I want to find all elements in that list that are `False` mixed between `True` elements. Meaning:

```
[True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False]
```

would yield nothing, and the list above should yield:

```
[1, 4]
```

I am currently just writing a loop which tries to remember the state walking that list backwards but I thought there might be a more efficient way. The index itself is not really needed as I am actually adding the elements which are unique to a list

Comment: Should ```[T,F,F,T]``` return ```[1,2]```?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi Yes

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
# zip both the array to create a tuple & yield those.
for index, (n, m) in enumerate(zip([True, False, True, False],
                                   [True, True, True, True])):
    if n != m:
        print(index)
```

Output

```
(1,3)
```

[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Can you add some comments about what this is doing

Comment: Interesting, so even if I wouldn't be interested in the index, I could drop the the `enumerate` and still do the comparison and add the result `if n != m` to my result set.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do it like this

```
test = [True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False]

start = None
found = None
end = None

for i in range(len(test)):
    if test[i] is False:
        if start is None:
            start = i
        else:
            found = i
    elif found is not None:
        end = found

if start is not None and end is not None:
    print(start)
    print(end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Create the list
li = [True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False]

# iterate from front until the first True value and remove all the False values
for i in li:
    if not i: li.pop()
    if i: break
# Out: [True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False]



# Iterate from back until the first True value and remove all the False values
for i in reversed(li):
    print(i)
    if i: break
    if not i: li.pop()
# Out: [True, False, True, True, False, True]

# Find the indices of remaining False values
[i for i,x in enumerate(li) if not x]
# Out: [1, 4]
```